# Using the Runge Kutta's Method to solve a 2nd derivative question

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Given that the motion of two bodies subject to a gravitational force of $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ = $\frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$, $x(0) = 0$, $\frac{dx}{dt}$$(0) = -0.5$  and $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ = $\frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$, $y(0) = 1$, $\frac{dy}{dt}(0) = -0.5$

It is also given that at those points given, the motion is periodic.

Find the largest and smallest $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$(distance between the two bodies).

**First thoughts:** I am only experienced working with just first derivative so I'm not really sure if I am supposed to use the Runge Kutta method two times to find the original. I will also be computing later via matlab and not by hand as the computations can get extremely difficult. However, I am stuck on just where to begin. Or is creating a systems of solutions the proper way to go about this question?

EDIT: searching around the internet, I read that it might be possible to solve this using a system of equations? So I created two matrices:

//sorry I'm unaware of how to create matrices:
Matrix 1: X' = [$x_2$ $\frac{-x_1}{(x_1^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$] but this should be 1 columned and two rows.

Matrix 2: X(0) = $[0, -0.5]^T$

Comment: I meant by Runge Kutta, been thinking of Newton's method all day and must have typed it subconsciously

Comment: For the integration of heavenly bodies using several methods ["Moving stars around"](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web/vol_1/v1_web/v1_web.html) is always a good read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an alternative method to my previous answer when the acceleration function is defined as a 2nd order diff. equation $$\ddot{\mathbf{Y}} = f(t,\mathbf{Y},\dot{\mathbf{Y}})$$

with the state vector $\mathbf{Y} = (x,y)$ in your case, holding the positions in the two coordinates, and $\mathbf{V} = \dot{\mathbf{Y}}= (\dot{x},\dot{y})$ holding the velocity vectors

$$ \begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x}\\ \ddot{y}\end{pmatrix} = f(t,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\ \dot{y}\end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}} \\ -\frac{y}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}\end{pmatrix} $$

Then you follow the following steps.

$$\begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{C}_0 &= \mathbf{V} & \mathbf{K}_0 & = f(t, \mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{C}_0) \\
  \mathbf{C}_1 &= \mathbf{V}+ \frac{h}{2} \mathbf{K}_0 & \mathbf{K}_1 & = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, \mathbf{Y} + \frac{h}{2} \mathbf{C}_0, \mathbf{C}_1)\\
  \mathbf{C}_2 &= \mathbf{V}+ \frac{h}{2} \mathbf{K}_1 & \mathbf{K}_2 & = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, \mathbf{Y} + \frac{h}{2} \mathbf{C}_1, \mathbf{C}_2) \\
  \mathbf{C}_3 &= \mathbf{V}+ h \mathbf{K}_2 & \mathbf{K}_3 & = f(t+h, \mathbf{Y} + h \mathbf{C}_2, \mathbf{C}_3)
\end{aligned} $$

and

$$\begin{aligned}
\Delta \mathbf{Y} & = \frac{h}{6} \left( \mathbf{C}_0 + 2 \mathbf{C}_1 + 2 \mathbf{C}_2 + \mathbf{C}_3 \right) \\ 
\Delta \mathbf{V} & = \frac{h}{6} \left( \mathbf{K}_0 + 2 \mathbf{K}_1 + 2 \mathbf{K}_2 + \mathbf{K}_3 \right)
\end{aligned}$$

Essentially your are running two Rk4 schemes in parallel, one for the positions and one for the velocities and you keep all cross term influences appropriately.

NOTE: The position step can be simplified to $\Delta \mathbf{Y}  = h \left(\mathbf{V}+\frac{h}{6} \left( \mathbf{K}_0 +  \mathbf{K}_1 +  \mathbf{K}_2  \right)\right) $.

Comment: Note that **boldface** variables denote 2×1 vectors.

Comment: I think this definitely answers my questions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have the following four, first order differential equations to solve using the standard RK4 method.

$$\dot{\mathbf{Y}} = f(t, \mathbf{Y})$$

where the state vector is $\mathbf{Y} = (x,y,v_x,v_y)$ in your case, holding the positions and velocities in the two coordinates.

$$\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{v}_x \\ \dot{v}_y  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} {v}_x \\ {v}_y \\ - \frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}} \\ - \frac{y}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}} \end{pmatrix} $$

So the steps are as follows:

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  \mathbf{K}_0 & = f(t, \mathbf{Y}) \\
  \mathbf{K}_1 & = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, \mathbf{Y} + \frac{h}{2} \mathbf{K}_0) \\
  \mathbf{K}_2 & = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, \mathbf{Y} + \frac{h}{2} \mathbf{K}_1) \\
  \mathbf{K}_3 & = f(t+h, \mathbf{Y} + h \mathbf{K}_2) \\
\end{aligned} $$

With the change in state vector as:

$$ \Delta \mathbf{Y} = \frac{h}{6} \left( \mathbf{K}_0 + 2 \mathbf{K}_1 + 2 \mathbf{K}_2 + \mathbf{K} \right) $$

Comment: Even though the question is second order differential, I can just treat it as a first order differential? Sorry I'm a little confused.

Comment: Yes, 1×2nd order = 2×1st order, or in your case 2×2nd order = 4×1st order.

Comment: Is this the correct way to proceed then?

k1 = $F(t,Y)$

k2 = $F(t + \frac{1}{2}h, y + \frac{1}{2}hk_1)$

k3 = $F(t+ \frac{1}{2}h, y+\frac{1}{2}hk_2)$

k4 = $F(t+h, Y + hk_3)$

Comment: See the steps above. Note that **boldface** variables denote 4×1 vectors.

Comment: Also as a matter of convention with programming `C` type languages, I use subscripts $0,1 \ldots 3$ for the four intermediate evaluations.